# why the slideshow not work using index array or index array.src

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple slideshow, just testing some ideas, which i would to expand on later on, with a few different audio, video  and pictures sources

Why is it if i type

```
var MySlides = [];
Myslides[0] = "link";
```

or

```
var MySlides = [];
MySlides[0].src = "link";
```

my slideshow not work, but if i type

```
var MySlides= ("link1","link2","link3") the slider work 'the links being 
 jpegs'
```

Is it because src is not a property of the object array, but
 if i stored the images in the array using the last method 
 and then married the array to the image array [i.e by index, 
 and then used src, it would work the same way as in the last method.
 is the benefit of the object, that it allows me to create my own 
 little mini program within the main program

i.e a booking system on one page for various companies

And lastily can anyone recommend and extensive reference sheet i can
use or convert to pdf to print, that shows the method, properties and 
event handlers of most objects, [ in a table format], with maybe a 
single working example,[wishful].

```
var MySlides = [];
 var Slider;

MySlides[0].src= "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/05/12/20/58/water-lilies-1388690_960_720.jpg";


MySlides[1].src= "http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg";


MySlides[2].src= "http://7606-presscdn-0-74.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Dubai-Photos-Images-Photos-of-Dubai-800x600.jpg";

Slider[3] = new Image();
MySlides[3].src= "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/05/12/20/58/water-lilies-1388690_960_720.jpg","http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg";


var Slide = 0;

function ShowSlides(SlideNumber) {

        Slide = Slide + SlideNumber;

        if (Slide > MySlides.length - 1){
            Slide = 0;
        }
        if (Slide < 0) {
            Slide = MySlides.length - 1;
        }
        document.DisplaySlide.src = MySlides[Slide];

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content ='width=device - width, initial-scale=1.0, user scalable=no'/>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<P align="center"><img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" name="DisplaySlide" width="900" height="320" /><p>

    <table border=0>
        <tr>
            <td align=center>
                <input id="left" type="button" value="Back" onclick="ShowSlides(-1)">
                <input type="button" value="Forward" onclick="ShowSlides(1)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
MySlides[0] = new Image();
MySlides[0].src= "...url...";
```

Which makes `MySlides[0]` an image object. You then do this:

```
document.DisplaySlide.src = MySlides[Slide];
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- image node
                     ^^^^--- src attribute of image nod
```

So you're assigning a full-blown Image object, to the `src` of a DOM img node. You can't do that. `src` expects a URL, and you're stuffing in an an object. It's like filling up a gasoline car with diesel, and then wondering why you can't drive anywhere.

Try

```
document.DisplaySlide.src = MySlides[Slide].src;
                                           ^^^^
```

instead.